# Multiple Instances of Firefox need to be invoked through web driver sampler of Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have created a Thread Group which has Firefox Driver Config , a Web driver Sampler and a View Results Tree Listener.
I have also added CSV Data set Config and passing username and Passwords through it to the application.
I have around 10 Credentials.

The scenario i want to do is, I want all the 10 users to login at the same time i.e 10 instances of the firefox browser to be invoked and do the job. i have given 10 in the thread group, but the users login 1 after the other.
Basically i am doing a performance testing, So i need all the 10 users to login at the same time(Simultaneously). So that 10 instances of firefox can be invoked at the same time.

Can anyone tell me, how can i achieve this in Jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

Just add [Synchronizing Timer](http://Using%20the%20JMeter%20Synchronizing%20Timer) to your test plan, if you need to test simultaneous login - put the timer as a child of login webdriver sampler.

I assume that you aware of recommendations from [WebDriver Sampler Tutorial](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) like

> It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

and

> JMeter allows the creation of multiple threads, and each thread is responsible for creating load on the server. However, for the Web Driver use case, the reader should be prudent in the number of threads they will create as each thread will have a single browser instance associated with it. Each browser consumes a significant amount of resources, and a limit should be placed on how many browsers the reader should create.

So it is recommended to create main load using JMeter's HTTP Request samplers and using one thread executing WebDriver Sampler to measure real-life user experience. If you still intend to create the main load with the WebDriver Sampler remember that browsers are resource-intensive so you'll need to provide something like 1 core and 1 Gb of RAM to each browser instance so make sure that machine(s) running JMeter have some capacity.